# Can anybody please help me with some URL rewriting?

Tags: .htaccess

I am in the development of a file sharing website now i want to create seo friendly urls.I tried different .htaccess codes to implement that Anybody please help me to implement that

I have a page `www.mydomain.com/gallery.php?id=2&title=newimage`

I want them to be requested as `www.mydomain.com/newimage/1.html`

Please give me .htaccess code to rewrite `www.mydomain.com/gallery.php?id=2&title=newimage`  to  `www.mydomain.com/newimage/1.html`

Comment: So the `gallery.php` id in your example is **2**, but in the friendly looking URL, you have `1.html`. So the **1** and **2** don't have anything to do with each other? Are you specifically rewriting that exact request to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the **1** and **2** are really the same id, you can add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ReewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.html$ /gallery.php?id=$2&title=$1 [L]
```

This makes it so when someone goes to `http://mydomain.com/foo/bar.html`, they get served the content at `/gallery.php?id=bar&title=foo`.

In order to correct all the external links beyond your control to start using the new nicer looking URL, you can add these too:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /gallery\.php\?id=([^&]+)&title=([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1.html? [L,R=301]
```

This makes it so when someone puts `http://mydomain.com/gallery.php?id=123456&title=blah`, the browser gets redirected to `http://mydomain.com/blah/123456.html`, thus changing the address in their browser's address bar to the nicer looking URL.